# What's the best way to use local packages in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, package-development

I'm a developer for a package (ycmd) used by spacemacs, and I'd like to try using spacemacs as well. I'd like spacemacs to use the "development version" of my package, i.e. the one I'm hacking on locally. What's the best/proper way to tell spacemacs to use that version of the package rather than the one from melpa?

Right now I'm using the `:load-path` argument to `use-package`, but this seems to go against the grain a bit. Does spacemacs let me specify a load directory for specific packages in the layer configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Local packages are put in `extensions.el` instead of `packages.el`. There are two lists in an `extensions.el` file:

- `<layer>-pre-extensions` which are loaded before `packages.el`
- `<layer>-post-extensions` which are loaded after `packages.el`

Local packages are put in the folder `extensions` within a sub-folder whose name is the name you put in one of the two lists. The `load-path` variable is handled automatically.

You can look at some examples in the `python` layer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I figured there was a canonical way, but I wasn't connecting all of the dots.

Comment: I edited the answer to mention the `load-path` variable which is automatically set.

Comment: @syl20bnr do you also need to add the package to `<layer>-excluded-packages, if you're working on a package already used elsewhere?

Comment: extensions.el is being deprecated in favour of local packages.  See https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/doc/LAYERS.org#packagesel

Comment: @tonyday indeed, the `python` layer that @syl20bnr mentions in this answer now follows those guidelines too, which had me confuddled until I saw your comment :)